# What does the second remark in Enderton's Logic book mean?

Tags: logic

Enderton's An Mathematical Introduction to Logic says on p115:

> A second remark:
>
> Taking all tautologies as logical axioms is overkill. We could get by with much less, at the expense of lengthening deductions.

Does "logical axioms" mean only those in axiom group 1, not other axiom groups? Because tautologies make sense only in group 1?

> On the one hand, the tautologies form a nice decidable set (the decidability will be important for the enumerability theorem in Section 2.5).
>
> On the other hand, there is no known fast decision procedure for tautologies, as noted in Section 1.7.
>
> One option would be to cut axiom group 1 down to a set of tautologies for which we do know decision procedures that are fast (the technical term is polynomial-time decidable).
> The other tautologies would then be obtainable from these by use of modus ponens.

isn't it that axiom group 1 consists of all the generalizations of the tautologies?
What does it mean by "cut axiom group 1 down to a set of tautologies"?

Which set of tautologies is axiom group 1 cut down to?
Is it the set of tautologies in Sentential Logic with sentence symbols being the wffs of FOL?
Is it the set of tautologies in Sentential Logic with sentence symbols being the prime wffs of FOL?

Why are the other tautologies "obtainable from these by modus ponens"?

Thanks.

Comment: It means that since there is no fast decision procedure for all tautologies, if one were to reduce the axioms in group 1 to a set of formulas that are polynomial-time decidable, then decidability results would follow more easily since the rest of the tautologies would follow from the ones that can be decided more quickly via Modus Ponens.

Comment: See also [your previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3770257/does-equivalence-between-different-deductive-systems-consider-choices-of-axioms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "logical axioms" are all of $\Lambda,$ i.e. all of groups 1-6.

"Taking all tautologies as logical axioms" means including all (generalizations of) tautologies in the logical axioms, which is what is done when we include all tautologies in group 1.

"Cut axiom group 1 down to a set of tautologies..." means that *instead* of including *all* tautologies in group 1, we would include only a specified subset of the tautologies that is still sufficient for completeness.

As to what set would be enough, Enderton isn't specific about this since it isn't the approach he is taking. His claim that you could do it with a subset that is efficiently verifiable would need to be justified, ideally by explicitly exhibiting such a set.

Many treatments of first-order logic don't take Enderton's official approach of including all tautologies, but rather take the approach that he's alluding to here. For instance P1-P4 in [the system on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system#Logical_axioms) gives a small set of efficiently verifiable tautologies that suffices for completeness.

In order to show these (or some other similar set) suffice, one needs to prove the completeness theorem for this superficially more limited deductive system. Alternatively, one can develop (as many non-Enderton texts do, e.g. Mendelson) a deductive system for propositional logic based on some limited set of axioms and modus ponens. The proof that such a propositional deductive system  is complete  amounts to a proof of the claim that "The other tautologies would then be obtainable from these by use of modus ponens".